# SQL index option Allow row lock, Allow page lock, should be set on or off? Is that possible to create periodically updated index?

Tags: sql-server, indexing, sql-server-2017, rowlocking

I have a very heavy update transaction based table

I am using an index to speed up pagination query

However the results read from the table is not important. I mean it doesnt have to be fully updated

So what actually these options do? I mean lets say if I set `Allow row locks` to false what happens? would it increase the speed?

Can i make such an index to be updated periodically instead of each transaction?

Lets say every 10 minutes index to be updated instead of every table update transaction is that possible?

[image]

Here actual execution plan of such query

https://pastebin.com/Vuwirip9

MS SQL Server 2017

thank you

Comment: I'd suggest asking this on DBA page. Will mark this question to be moved there so you can get crowd that will be able to help you faster.

Comment: *However the results read from the table is not important*. If this is the case, why not use `NOLOCK` table hint and leave these global settings alone? You seem to only care about a *single* table. Besides, if you disable page locks you can't reorganize your index. Updating an index (defrag / reorg) every 10 min soulds insane. Instead, just show us your query... the query plan and we can help troubleshoot the query itself. [Check out this blog](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2009/03/getting-help-with-a-slow-query/) and [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)

Comment: @scsimon yes i am already using no lock. but you know each time it sorts entire table based on a column to fetch certain pages. what i am trying to achive is minizing index update COST when table is updated.

Comment: So you are trying to optimize the `INSERTS` and `UPDATES`, not `SELECT` queries. This still needs to go on dba.stackexchange.com but we still need to see the execution plan. Meanwhile [Paul White](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/1192/paul-white) has written a [blog on this](https://sqlperformance.com/2015/12/sql-plan/optimizing-update-queries). Also, [Michael Swart](http://michaeljswart.com/2017/07/sql-server-upsert-patterns-and-antipatterns/) has as well.

Comment: @scsimon you mean XML of execution plan right? here it is > https://pastebin.com/Vuwirip9 . Also yes i am trying to optimize insert and updates. thank you

Comment: Yes, but better [At this site](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=rk3HKOWWV) which I've posted for you. This isn't an `UPDATE` query though... is this just a segment of it? I'm not sure why you chose to use a CTE or a sub-query in the CTE just to join back to it. This could be simplified if you'd like that?